# Metropolis within Gibbs

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I have the following variables: $\beta,\Omega,\tau$. $\tau$ is a hyperparameter for the prior on $\beta$.

For a fixed $\tau$, I have the conditionals:$p(\Omega|\beta),p(\beta|\Omega)$. To generate samples from the joint distribution, I would adopt the following Gibbs Sampling scheme at each time $t$.

1. Sample $\Omega^{t+1}\sim p(\Omega|\beta^t)$
2. Sample $\beta^{t+1}\sim p(\beta|\Omega^{t+1})$

This is straightforward in the case of fixed $\tau$. In the case that I also place a prior on $\tau$. I think I would augment the sampling scheme as follows if I knew how to sample from the $\tau$ conditional.

1. Sample $\Omega^{t+1}\sim p(\Omega|\beta^t,\tau^t)$
2. Sample $\beta^{t+1}\sim p(\beta|\Omega^{t+1},\tau^t)$
3. Sample $\tau^{t+1}\sim p(\tau|\beta^{t+1},\Omega^{t})$

Unfortunately, I do not think I have a nice way to obtain the conditional distribution of $\tau|\beta,\Omega$. Instead, I was considering generating a sample from that distribution using a single Metropolis step, where I know that density up to proportionality constant by Bayes Rule. I have not considered this before, and thought it was strange that the conditional density of $\beta|\Omega,\tau$ would be reused in this way.

$$
p(\tau|\beta,\Omega)\propto p(\beta|\Omega,\tau)p(\tau)
$$

Thus, I would compute the acceptance probability for a single Metropolis step with proposal density $q(.)$.

$$
a=min(1,\frac{p(\tau^*|\beta^{t+1},\Omega^{t+1})p(\tau^*)q(\tau|\tau^*)}{p(\tau|\beta^{t+1},\Omega^{t+1})p(\tau)q(\tau^*|\tau)})
$$

Is this idea mistaken?

Comment: Your notations seem to imply that $\Omega$ also depends on $\tau$, in which case$$p(\tau|\beta,\Omega)\propto p(\beta,\Omega|\tau)p(\tau)$$and $\alpha$ need be modified accordingly. But your understanding is otherwise correct.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you!